# iPad pop over view slides from the bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to build a view to my application Settings that is very much like most iPad apps do - a small window slides up from the bottom and present you with the settings on a uitableview. Once this page gets to the main window, the background is dimmed.

How can I achieve something like that? Which class to use? Is this a regular uiviewcontroller?

Any guidance, including a sample app would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a UIViewController that's presented modally. Search `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: Does this dim the background too? It would help if moshikafya could add an example screenshot.

Comment: You can have a dimmed background. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to present a view controller modally.  You can read all about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).